# refresh google map in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, google-maps-api-2

I created simple android application in which i used google maps.

Now in this Map Activity i created option menu and in this when one particular item is selected i opened another activity.

Now the problem is that activity is containing only one list view and when any particular list item is selected i am again starting the Map activity using intent.

Now according to the item selected the changes must me reflected, i mean to say i want to clear the particular googel map and again load it.

Should i use recreate method to refresh it or there is any other option available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a [`clear()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#clear%28%29) method you can use:

From the Docs:

> Removes all markers, polylines, polygons, overlays, etc from the map.

Comment: can you tell me which event will be fired when i am selecting particular item in list and i am again starting the activity using intent. Like onResume() or what so i can put my code there?

Comment: if you are using an intent to start a new Activity, then you will go throgh all the lifecicle of the Activity so you can place it anywhere you like. in onCreate or onResume. what suit you best.